# How to add another icon to a p-panel

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to add another icon apart from expand and close in this p-panel, but it depends on an id that I get from the `getDetailGrade(tool.id)` function:

**TS:**

```
    dataGrid: any;
    dataGridBrokenDown: any;
    infoGrade: any;
    hideTooltip: boolean;

    getDetailGrade(data) {
        this.gradeService.getGradeBookById(data).then(
            resCatalog => {
                this.dataGrid = resCatalog;
                console.log(this.dataGrid);
                this.hideTooltip=false;
                this.infoGrade="Something";
            }
        );
    }
```

**SCSS:**

```
.icon_grade {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 82px;
    background: url('../../../assets/icon/designer/book.svg');
    background-size: 100px 82px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
     <p-panel [toggleable]="true"
         (click)="onClickElement(tool.properties, i, tool)"
         [pSelectableRow]="getDetailGrade(tool.id)"
         [pTooltip]="infoGrade" [tooltipDisabled]="hideTooltip">
         [ngClass]="dataGrid !== null? tool.id:'icon_grade'">
    {{tool.id}}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p-panel>
```

```
    <ng-template *ngIf="dataGrid !== null; else showIcon"></ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="iconGrade" #showIcon>
        <i class="icon_grade"></i>
    </ng-template>
```

Only if I put it inside an ng-template it appears, but I don't want it like that, I want it inside the p-panel header (this icon in the header is the example of what I want to achieve):

[image]

But I don't know how to do it, the above are some attempts of what I have done and nothing is shown. I've searched various stack overflow questions and various sites, but can't find an example or satisfactory answer,I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You should add the `<ng-template>` inside the `<p-panel>` and the name should be `icons` (`pTemplate="icons"`). There's an example in the official docs: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/panel (ctrl+f Custom Icons)

Comment: Yes, in fact I have that same one busy for the delete button icon, I just didn't put the complete code.
`<ng-template pTemplate="icons" class="colorIcons">
<button pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-times" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text" (click)="deleteBlock(tool.id)"></button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
div class="text-center">
<h4 class="my-3">{{tool.name + '&nbsp;' + tool.allData?.history}}   <i [class]="tool.inOutType === 'In' ? 'pi pi-sign-in' : 'pi pi-sign-out'"></i> </h4>
</div>
</ng-template>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass on `pTemplate="icons"`, which can contain multiple icons as you need.

```
<p-panel
  [toggleable]="true"
  [pTooltip]="infoGrade"
  [tooltipDisabled]="hideTooltip"
>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <ng-template pTemplate="icons">
    <button
      pButton
      class="p-panel-header-icon p-link"
      (click)="menu.toggle($event)"
    >
      <span class="pi pi-cog"></span>
    </button>
    <p-menu #menu id="config_menu" [model]="items" [popup]="true"></p-menu>
    <i class="icon_grade"></i>
  </ng-template>
</p-panel>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-panel-demo-hqexgz)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, already it appears inside the p-panel, but a line appears above the pi-times icon, how do I make it appear next to it and for the validation to work for me? Here is the change:
`<ng-template pTemplate="icons" class="colorIcons">
      <i [ngClass]="{'icon_issue_tp': tool.id !== null}"></i>
      <button pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-times" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text" (click)="deleteBlock(tool.id)"></button>
</ng-template>`